# Draw points in tikz with foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, literate-programming

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[portuguese, shorthands=off]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}


\foreach \i in {1,...,5}{
\foreach \j in {1,...,5}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (-4.,-4.) rectangle (4.,4.);
\draw[help lines,step=1,densely dotted, gray!80] (-3,-3) grid (3,3);
\draw[->,-latex',line width=1pt] (-3,0) -- (3,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[->,-latex',line width=1pt] (0,-3) -- (0,3) node[above]{$y$};

\foreach \a in {1,...,\i}{
    \foreach \b in {1,...,\j}{
        \draw[fill=blue,draw=blue] ({\a-3},{\b-3}) circle (1pt);
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
}

\end{document}
```

My intention is create a different figure for each point that is inserted. I want to plot one-by-one plotting the points in this sequence:

`(-2,-2), (-2,-1) .... (-2,2)` -> next
`(-1,-2), (-1,-1),....,(-1,2)` -> next
`(0,-2), (0,-1),...,(0,2)` -> next
.....
`(2,-2), (2,-1),...,(2,2)`.

In each new figure, I want to preserve the points generated in the previous iteration.

How can I adapt my code to do this?

Comment: Not related to the problem, but you should not load packages more than once (`tikz`, `pgfplots`).

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
%\usepackage[portuguese, shorthands=off]{babel} 
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
%\usepackage{xfp}
%\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}


\foreach \i in {0,...,24}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (-4.,-4.) rectangle (4.,4.);
\draw[help lines,step=1,densely dotted, gray!80] (-3,-3) grid (3,3);
\draw[->,-latex',line width=1pt] (-3,0) -- (3,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[->,-latex',line width=1pt] (0,-3) -- (0,3) node[above]{$y$};

\foreach \a in {0,...,\i}
        \draw[fill=blue,draw=blue] ({int(\a/5)-2},{mod(\a,5)-2}) circle (1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: not bad indeed +1